EAS iOS Build failed
EAS iOS build keeps on getting failed.
This is an expo bare project.
Tried on both Windows and Mac but it keeps on failing every time.
The app is working fine on Expo Go. Also, the Android apk and app-bundle are built without any problem.
This is my package.json file
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts,.tsx --quiet"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^7.0.9",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.17.11",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "6.7.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.7",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "5.12.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.15",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "5.14.5",
    "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.5",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "d3-shape": "^3.2.0",
    "dayjs": "1.10.5",
    "expo": "^48.0.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "2.0.0",
    "expo-blur": "~12.2.2",
    "expo-build-properties": "^0.6.0",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.3.1",
    "expo-clipboard": "~4.1.2",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-device": "~5.2.1",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.2.2",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.2.2",
    "expo-haptics": "~12.2.1",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.1.2",
    "expo-localization": "~14.1.1",
    "expo-network": "~5.2.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "formik": "^2.4.2",
    "i18n-js": "3.8.0",
    "lottie-colorify": "^0.8.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.4",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "moment-hijri": "^2.1.2",
    "native-base": "^3.4.28",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.14",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-chart-kit": "^6.12.0",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-dns-lookup": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-image-slider-box": "^2.0.7",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "0.9.4",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^15.0.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-sectioned-multi-select": "^0.10.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-svg-charts": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.2",
    "react-native-table-component": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-user-inactivity": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.0",
    "react-native-vpn-status": "^0.1.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.11",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.26.0",
    "rn-pdf-reader-js-improved": "^1.0.0",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.13",
    "victory-native": "^36.6.10",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
    "@types/i18n-js": "3.8.1",
    "@types/react": "~18.0.27",
    "@types/react-native-svg-charts": "^5.0.12",
    "@types/react-native-table-component": "^1.2.4",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.13",
    "eslint": "7.28.0",
    "jest-expo": "^48.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "private": true,
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|@sentry/.*)"
    ]
  }
}

And these are the last few lines of eas logs where build failed
> ARCHIVE FAILED **
> 1464
> The following build commands failed:
> 1465▸ 
> PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlomInvest-bzgpuvoqnyjbencycfehxafsvgtm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/BlomInvest/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-46EB2E0001C790.sh (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')
> 1466
> ▸ (1 failure)
> 1467
> ARCHIVE FAILED **
> 146814691470
> The following build commands failed:
> 1471
> PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlomInvest-bzgpuvoqnyjbencycfehxafsvgtm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/BlomInvest/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-46EB2E0001C790.sh (in target 'FBReactNativeSpec' from project 'Pods')
> 1472
> (1 failure)
> 1473
> Exit status: 65
> 14741475
> +---------------------------------------+
> 1476
> Build environment           |
> 1477
> +-------------+-------------------------+
> 1478
> xcode_path  | /Applications/Xcode.app |
> 1479
> gym_version | 2.217.0                 |
> 1480
> sdk         | iPhoneOS17.2.sdk        |
> 1481
> +-------------+-------------------------+
> 14821483
> Looks like fastlane ran into a build/archive error with your project
> 1484
> It's hard to tell what's causing the error, so we wrote some guides on how
> 1485
> to troubleshoot build and signing issues: 
> 1486
> Before submitting an issue on GitHub, please follow the guide above and make
> 1487
> sure your project is set up correctly.
> 1488
> fastlane uses `xcodebuild` commands to generate your binary, you can see the
> 1489
> the full commands printed out in yellow in the above log.
> 1490
> Make sure to inspect the output above, as usually you'll find more error information there
> 1491
> Error building the application - see the log above
> 1492
> Error: The "Run fastlane" step failed with an unknown error. Refer to "Xcode Logs" below for additional, more detailed logs.
> Script has ambiguous dependencies causing it to run on every build.
> To fix, go to: Xcode » BlomInvest/BlomInvest » Build Phases » 'Start Packager'
> Either: Uncheck "Based on dependency analysis", or select output files to trigger the script
> Script has ambiguous dependencies causing it to run on every build.
> To fix, go to: Xcode » BlomInvest/BlomInvest » Build Phases » 'Bundle React Native code and images'
> Either: Uncheck "Based on dependency analysis", or select output files to trigger the script
> Script has ambiguous dependencies causing it to run on every build.
> To fix, go to: Xcode » BlomInvest/BlomInvest » Build Phases » '[CP-User] [RNFB] Core Configuration'
> Either: Uncheck "Based on dependency analysis", or select output files to trigger the script
>  
> https://docs.fastlane.tools/codesigning/getting-started/

